# Rabbitmq high watermark set issue

Tags: rabbitmq

This is what i'm getting in rabbitmq message broker

=INFO REPORT==== 13-Jan-2015::12:40:24 ===
vm_memory_high_watermark set. Memory used:478063864 allowed:415868518

=WARNING REPORT==== 13-Jan-2015::12:40:24 ===
memory resource limit alarm set on node 'rabbit@matchpointgps-141110'.

---

*** Publishers will be blocked until this alarm clears ***

---

This has happened twice at our server.
I'm still not able to get the correct solution for this.

Answer (score 2):

We had a similar issue when the queue lengths got very high and it tried to write the messages to disk but couldn't do it fast enough.  In our testing, we did not have this problem when we used SSD drives.

The easiest solution for us was to have the messages written to disk immediately by setting durable=true on the messages.  This was also a good idea because if rabbit restarted the data in the queues wouldn't be lost.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue in a rabbitMQ server running on docker. Everything was blocked and rabbit won't accept any message.

I simply did to reconfigure the [Disk Free Space Limit](https://www.rabbitmq.com/disk-alarms.html#configure):

```
rabbitmqctl set_disk_free_limit 1GB
```

This changed the "xx GiB low watermark" and solved the problem.

If you are using a "bitnami/rabbitmq" docker image, you can set this varibale with:

```
RABBITMQ_DISK_FREE_ABSOLUTE_LIMIT: "1GB"
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this blog post on how RabbitMQ queues use memory: http://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2011/10/27/performance-of-queues-when-less-is-more/

TL;DR try to keep your queues as empty as possible

Answer (score 0):

Finally, found some better configuration for rabbitmq queues.

I've added following line to celery config since it was creating one additional queue for each tasks.

CELERY_IGNORE_RESULT = True

And also created separate queue for my task.
This keeps the memory free and ready to take up more heavy and longer tasks

more information
https://denibertovic.com/posts/celery-best-practices/

Answer (score 0):

By default, RabbitMQ will block incoming messages if it starts to use above 40% of the available ram. If you open the 'rabbitmq.conf' file (usually saved in the AppData folder on your computer) you can increase that. I changed my to 90% by adding this line:

vm_memory_high_watermark.relative = 0.9

You'll have to reset the RabbitMQ service after doing this to see the effect.